# How to fix broken R package dependencies after a libgfortran.so update

Tags: linux, updates, r, dependencies

*[In practice this should apply to all Lx distros, and "conceptually" to all Apple and M$ OSes as well.]*

Upgrading R [base] on your system may sometimes break some dependencies 
, depending on the packages you have installed and use by calling:
`library("package_name")`.
This happened to me recently after a routine rolling release update. Here's the message I got:

> unable to load shared object
>   `/home/USER/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/leaps/libs/leaps.so`:
>   libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[image: package_dep_install_error]

I've seen  quite a few posts on SE, Github and elsewhere with similar reports but no solution (at least for me).

- Reinstalling R base does do any good or bad or anything.
- Another things that comes to mind is to downgrade and remove latest packages to return to a previous version state. Not satisfactory and complicated to maintain for rolling releases such as Arch Lx.

So how do you fix this at 7pm, when you need to put R to work "now" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** `$ find /usr/lib/ -name "libgfortran.*"`
Convince yourself that simply making up the missing symbolic link
`libgfortran.so.4 -> libgfortran.so.5.0.0` does not help at all.
 (Target's version info "5.0.0" in the symbolic link, will vary depending on installed versions.)

**2)** Find out  **exactly**  which dependencies are broken. This is a function of your installed packages. (Replace `/3.x` in path below by whatever version of `R base` you use.)

```
$ ldd ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.x/*/libs/*.so \
  | egrep '(so:$|not found)' > ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.x/foobar
```

`ldd` prints shared object dependencies. Any line in `foobar` preceding a line where *"not found"* shows refers to a broken package that needs removing and reinstalling.

**3)** Move previously identified broken packages's folders to a backup folder of yr choice. Yr R packages are normally installed in `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.x/` by default on lx. (Any other location must be specified by you during install or globally in your R configuration file.) From the R console, reinstall removed packages:
 
`> install.packages(c("pkg_name_1","pkg_name_2",...), depend=T)`
Note that not `(removing | moving)` existing (broken) packages from their location, and proceeding with reinstalling them will not fix anything. You need to move broken packages' folders away from their location, so R may rebuild dependencies.

**4)** Load R libraries of interest and perform ad hoc tests from the R console, before removing 
`~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.x/foobar`.

HTH.